# InvalidRequest to add ColumnDefinition to Sharepoint List using Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm using the Microsoft Graph SDK for C# ASP.NET, and I'm having an error when I try to add a new ColumnDefinition to some list in Sharepoint. The exception that returns from the SDK just says "InvalidRequest". I already tried a lot of changes but could not find any soluction. When using Graph Explorer, the column is added normally.

NOTES:

- The list type is a document library called (Document_2022_6)
- The document library exists on Sharepoint
- The document library contains some documents
- Microsoft Graph SDK version: 4.45.0
- When creating the document library from scratch, the column is added normally
- The error only occurs when document library is already created
- I'm using Sharepoint Online
- Using Graph Explorer, **it works**

The code I'm using to add the column is:

```cs
public async Task<bool> CreateColumnInDocumentLibrary(string columnName, string DriveListId)
{

    ColumnDefinition newColumn = SetColumnDefinition(columnName); // columnName = "DocTags"
    var createColumn = await _graphServiceClient
        .Sites[siteId] // <site-id>
        .Lists[DriveListId] // DriveListId = "c018992b-d95d-453a-9eff-9f17fb89cde6" (Document_2022_6)
        .Columns
        .Request()
        .AddAsync(newColumn); // Raises the exception
    return createColumn != null;
}

private ColumnDefinition SetColumnDefinition(string columnName)
{
    ColumnDefinition newColumn = new ColumnDefinition
    {
        Name = columnName, // columnName = "DocTags"
        DisplayName = columnName, // columnName = "DocTags"
        Description = columnName, // columnName = "DocTags"
        Indexed = true,
        Hidden = false,
        IsReorderable = true,
        Text = new TextColumn
        {
            AllowMultipleLines = false,
            AppendChangesToExistingText = false,
            LinesForEditing = 0,
            MaxLength = 255
        }
    };
    return newColumn;
}
```

---

```
Exception Details:
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
Error Code: invalidRequest
Message: Invalid request
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2022-10-25T12:08:21
    request-id: c2b72b14-a0f8-4b40-bb7e-...
    client-request-id: c2b72b14-a0f8-4b40-bb7e-...

Raw Response Body: "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"invalidRequest\",\"message\":\"Invalid request\",\"innerError\":{\"date\":\"2022-10-25T12:08:21\",\"request-id\":\"c2b72b14-a0f8-4b40-bb7e-63c71d3e6686\",\"client-request-id\":\"c2b72b14-a0f8-4b40-bb7e-63c71d3e6686\"}}}"
```

---

The request below was used with Microsoft Graph Explorer, and it worked successfully.

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<site-id>/lists/c018992b-d95d-453a-9eff-9f17fb89cde6/columns 

{
    "description": "DocTags",
    "displayName": "DocTags",
    "name": "DocTag",
    "indexed": true,
    "isReordable": true,
    "text": {
        "allowMultipleLines": false,
        "appendChangesToExistingText": false,
        "linesForEditing": 0,
        "maxLength": 255
    }
}

Response 200 OK:

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites(<site-id>)/lists('c018992b-d95d-453a-9eff-9f17fb89cde6')/columns/$entity",
    "columnGroup": "Custom Columns",
    "description": "DocTags",
    "displayName": "DocTags",
    "enforceUniqueValues": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "id": "491bb2de-4d77-4dde-b376-b9df6f69fae8",
    "indexed": true,
    "name": "DocTags",
    "readOnly": false,
    "required": false,
    "text": {
        "allowMultipleLines": false,
        "appendChangesToExistingText": false,
        "linesForEditing": 0,
        "maxLength": 255
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the issue is that you are trying to create a column that you have already created by graph explorer. Try to use different column than "DocTags" in C# app.

Comment: I tried using different doc libs, ensuring that there was no column already created. I even tried with different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the documentation, I noticed that the field `IsReorderable` is Read-Only. Because of that, the request was becoming malformed to the Graph API. After removing the line `IsReorderable = true`, it worked.

Solution:

```cs
private ColumnDefinition SetColumnDefinition(string columnName)
{
    ColumnDefinition newColumn = new ColumnDefinition
    {
        Name = columnName,
        DisplayName = columnName,
        Description = columnName,
        Indexed = true,
        Hidden = false,
        // IsReorderable = true, [Remove]
        Text = new TextColumn
        {
            AllowMultipleLines = false,
            AppendChangesToExistingText = false,
            LinesForEditing = 0,
            MaxLength = 255
        }
    };
    return newColumn;
}
```

Comment: Doc link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/columndefinition?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Strange that you sent "isReordable": true in request for Graph Explorer and it worked.

Comment: Yes. Maybe the Graph Explorer apply some consistency rules after send the request to the API.